# How do I specify a channel name with spaces?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I created a join command for my discord.py bot, but if ill specify a channel name with spaces, it wont connect to him. It throws an AttributeError, which indicates that the channel could not be found.

```
    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx, channelname):
        channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=channelname)
        await channel.connect()
```

Comment: Can you enclose the channel name in quotes `name=‘My Channel Name’`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `*` before the final argument to take in the full string like this:

```py
async def join(ctx, *, args):
```

So your function will look like this:

```py
@commands.command()
async def join(ctx, *, channelname):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name = channelname)
    await channel.connect()
```